# Java vs C JNI - UDP performance

Tags: java, c, networking, java-native-interface, udp

I am currently writing a Java client to communicate to a server using UDP.

If one wanted pure UDP performance with packet throughput, would there be any advantage to writing the UDP networking communication in C and passing the data to it from java via JNI. Or would the overhead of JNI remove any performance gained by sending the packets in C?]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overhead of the network would dominate any possible difference. The extra complication of JNI and the immense extra complication of writing networking code in C just isn't worth it. Forget it.

Comment: EJP is correct in that the performance difference between native IO and Java IO is going to be negligible.  However, you man need JNI to accomplish some socket related activity that is not supported by the JVM. (Ex: ICMP)  In thouse situations something like [Java RAW sockets](http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/) whould be worth taking a look at.